# How to add row in MySQL what does not exist when selecting it

Tags: mysql, sql-server, lua

I created table to database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `highscores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vocation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `kills` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deaths` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `monster` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And now I want to use LUA language to insert and update things in that table:

```
function highscore(accID, monster, vocation)
print("ERROR HERE?")
local results = db.storeQuery("SELECT 'id' FROM 'highscores' WHERE 'account_id' = "..accID.." AND 'vocation' = "..vocation.." AND 'monster' = "..monster)
print("OR ERROR HERE?")
    if not results then
        db.query("INSERT INTO highscores('account_id', 'attempts', 'kills', 'deaths', 'vocation', 'monster') VALUES ("..accID..","..(0)..","..(0)..","..(0)..","..vocation..","..monster..")")
    end
print()
```

The function continues, but I already have problems here.
I get errors twice, for trying to SELECT and for trying to INSERT.
It says that my syntax does not correspond to MySQL version...

Also tried this instead of the above. Same problem, syntax error:

```
db.query("INSERT INTO 'highscores'('account_id', 'vocation', 'kills', 'deaths', 'attempts', 'monster') SELECT * FROM (SELECT "..accID..","..vocation..","..(0)..","..(0)..","..(0)..","..monster.." WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'account_id' FROM 'highscores' WHERE 'account_id' = "..accID.." AND 'vocation' = "..vocation.." AND 'monster' = "..monster..") LIMIT 1;")
```

Even if I manually insert the correct value it should insert automatically.
and then I try to select it, it gives me syntax error.

I do not have this problem with any other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think your quotes are in the wrong place; instead of

```
"SELECT 'id' FROM 'highscores' WHERE 'account_id' = "..accID.." AND 'vocation' = "..vocation
.." AND 'monster' = "..monster
```

you should probably have:

```
([[SELECT id FROM highscores WHERE account_id = %s AND vocation = "%s" AND monster = "%s"]])
:format(accID, vocation, monster)
```

In your case you'd have `WHERE 'account_id' = 123 AND 'vocation' = something` whereas it should probably be `WHERE account_id = 123 AND vocation = 'something'` (assuming `accID` has only numeric values).